# Why does cron (DEC OSF1 V4.0 1229 alpha) send mail from a user without a crontab?

Tags: unix, cron

I cannot seem to find an answer for this anywhere. Superuser *root* has a crontab with a couple of jobs that send the resultant output to *root's* mailbox addressed **from** my non-superuser account *foo*.

It is my understanding that the owner of the cron job is supposed to be the sender of the resultant cron job output. Account *foo* does not have a crontab, and in-fact I have even tried explicitly removing *foo's* crontab, but still *root* receives *root's* cron job output from user *foo*.

When I edit *root's* crontab, I log into the system as *foo*, and then `su -` to *root*. Does this have anything to do with it?

When I `ls -alF /var/spool/cron/crontabs` there is no file for user *foo*.

Does anyone know why my non-superuser account *foo*, that does not have a crontab file, seems to be sending mail to superuser *root*?

It also seems that for some of *root's* cron jobs, that it executes as *root* **and** as *foo* which both send email to *root's* mailbox.

Example:

From foo Sat Oct 30 19:01:01 2010
Received: by XXXXXX (8.8.8/1.1.22.3/15Jan03-1152AM)
        id TAA0000027883; Sat, 30 Oct 2010 19:01:01 -0400 (EDT)
Date: Sat, 30 Oct 2010 19:01:01 -0400 (EDT)
From: foo 
Message-Id: <201010302301.TAA0000027883@XXXXXX>

*redacted*

---

Cron: The previous message is the standard output
      and standard error of one of your cron commands.

From root Sat Oct 30 19:01:01 2010
Received: by XXXXXX (8.8.8/1.1.22.3/15Jan03-1152AM)
        id TAA0000025999; Sat, 30 Oct 2010 19:01:01 -0400 (EDT)
Date: Sat, 30 Oct 2010 19:01:01 -0400 (EDT)
From: system privileged account 
Message-Id: <201010302301.TAA0000025999@XXXXXX>

*redacted*

---

Cron: The previous message is the standard output
      and standard error of one of your cron commands.

Comment: What commands do you use to edit the crontab (`crontab -e`?) - edit you post to include the actual crontab entry in question - which cron daemon is running (e.g. `vixie-cron`)? Somebody might be able to push you in the right direction if you provide more information of that kind.

Answer (score 0):

You should show us the actual crontab entry. Some crons allow to specify a user, not just a command. If that user doesn't have a mailbox, maybe by default cron sends the output to root's inbox with the sender still set to 'foo' (which is easily done by having `From: foo` in the mail header.)

Answer (score 0):

vixie-cron supports a system-wide crontab file in `/etc/crontab` that allows per-user cron jobs to be specified.  The syntax is similar to the usual cron syntax except a username is specified in the 6th column, and the command to be run follows that.  For example:

```
0 22 * * 1-5   foo   mail -s "Mail to root from foo" root
```

So check `/etc/crontab` for any entries with `foo` in the 6th column.